# jQuery - how can I get a value of the next option in a dropdown after the selected one?

Tags: jquery, html-select

I have a drop down with a selected option at index = 0.
How can I in jquery get the value of the next option at index = 1?
Of course I need to do that without specifying the value of the next option because I can;t assume what it will be at this point.

thx

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can write

```
$('#dropDownId option:selected').next().val()
```

Or

```
$('#dropDownId option:selected+option').val()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $('#selectid option:selected').next().val()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('#selectId>option:selected').next().val()
```